# Can I use an else if expression in qlikview?

Tags: expression, qlikview

I am using qlikview and I have a Pivottable. In that table I am trying to have a formel field in that I am asking three different things. I've tried to use an Else-if Statement like in the script but it didn'dt worked out this time.

So the question is: is there a possibility to state an Else-if function in the Expression blockor is it necessary to Change the view it is based on?

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

You can nest if statements;

```
=sum(if(A=B, Field1, if(A=C, Field2, Field3)))
```

Comment: Is it possible to Count the result of the nested if-statements?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you provide an example of what you want to accomplish?

Comment: Sure I have a List of Projects with three different Status and Types.
So P1 = active/ Type A , P2 = closed? Type =A, P3 = future/ Type B and P4 = active/ Type C. Now I try to get a List of this Projects and the Count of how many of them are in a specific Status ordered by type.
This means if I searching for Status activethe result should be
P1 Type A = 1
P4 Type C = 1

Answer (score 0):

Question is not clear and you didn't post any code or a result example but I'll try:

if in the script you separate the project field (with [subfield](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/3.0/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Scripting/StringFunctions/SubField.htm)) to
`Project`, `Status` & and `Type` then you can use something like

```
count({<status={'active'}>} total <Project,Type> Project)
```

depends on your pivot (as you didn't post an example...), maybe you won't need the `total <Project,Type>`